# While cycle with time duration on include

Tags: php

I need to create a cycle to end when it is longer than 20 seconds.
I have tried the following code but it's not working, running forever.

**EDIT**:
For simple code it will stop fine, but using the include_once and include the external files keep running even after the 20 seconds expire

**bot.php**

```
$starttime = time();


while (time() - $starttime < 20) {    

 include_once 'onefile.php';
 include 'somefile.php';
 include 'somefile2.php';

}
```

**EDIT 2**:

With Josh Trii Johnston's answer the proccess is really stopped if not concluded within X seconds. The problem now is that there is another requisit on my case.. The sample provided above does not run alone. It is also included on another loop file like this:

**master.php**

```
<?php
       while (1) {   
            include 'bot.php'; 
            sleep(60);
        }
```

As you can see it is running on a infinite loop and what I want is not stop the entire loop but only "break" the bot.php loop, keeping the main while(1) loop active. With the provided solution it exits all the loops and the process is terminated.

Comment: @Barmar yes you are absolutley right

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked fine.

Comment: See working demo: http://ideone.com/AtZ6X3

Comment: Most probably, there is some memory overflow in your code.

Comment: Yeah, memory is racking up too fast, but here's another demo that seems to work with certain versions.. you may have to inclrease the memeory limit on your script though: https://3v4l.org/QtsO7

Comment: Yeah. I see that the code works with simple "/// CODE". I have edited original description. I am using - include 'file.php'; and that doesn't stop that way. It doesn't stop running the files wich are in fact a little bit big +- 10 minutes. I am putting the 20 second to hit and test if the timelimit works effectivelly

Comment: Well there's your problem. The `include` is synchronous, it doesn't matter if you wrap a `while` around it. By the time it reaches the next iteration (**after** the `include` has completed), assuming your file takes longer than 20 seconds to load, it'll have satisfied the while condition by then.

Comment: @sjagr is there any similar code that I can use here?

Comment: I would try @JoshTriiJohnston's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP is not magic and cannot stop execution mid-script like that. The `while` condition is only checked once all processing inside your `include`s are completed.

You can try calling `register_tick_function()` and provide a callback that can check the time elapsed and `exit` if needed.

**Now with more example!**

```
<?php
declare(ticks=1);

define('START_TIME', time());

// lambda uses START_TIME constant
register_tick_function(function() {
    if (time() - START_TIME > 20) {
        echo 'Script execution halted. Took more than 20 seconds to execute';
        exit(1);
    }
}, true);

include_once 'onefile.php';
include 'somefile.php';
include 'somefile2.php';
?>
```

This will halt on the next [`tick`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks) that happens after the 20 second mark, not exactly 20 seconds.

**Edit #2 Working code based on your current updates**

This code works on a similar principle but instead of halting script execution, it throws a `TimeLimitException` which is then used to jump to a point of execution using [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php). It is hacky, but it accomplishes what you need.

```
<?php
declare(ticks=1);

$start_time = time();
class TimeLimitException extends Exception {}

// lambda uses $start_time global so it can reset
// the timer after the time limit is reached
register_tick_function(function() {
    global $start_time;
    if (time() - $start_time > 20) {
        echo 'Script execution halted. Took more than 20 seconds to execute', PHP_EOL;
        $start_time = time();
        throw new TimeLimitException();
    }
}, true);

try {
    // time limit will reset to here. Cannot jump to a label in a loop
    limit:

    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        echo 'outer ';
        while (1) {
            echo 'inner ';
            sleep(2);
        }
    }
} catch (TimeLimitException $e) {
    echo 'time limit hit, jumping to label `limit`', PHP_EOL;
    goto limit;
}
```

Comment: seems a good solution but not sure how to implement it. Will take a deeper look

Comment: Worked like a charm! Just had to change "<" for ">". You mistaken there.

Comment: Sorry about that. I cut n pasted from your original code and didn't verify first.

Comment: With proper testing I could conclude that this solution does not fix my problem.. Pls check the edited description. Sorry :\

Comment: @ace I forgot all about this earlier this month. I've added a new solution that solves your problem based upon my understanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, something like [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-time-limit.php) is a better approach.

Alternatively, if you just want to limit the includetime, do Threads.

```
class workerThread extends Thread {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->starttime=time();
    }

    public function run(){
        include_once 'onefile.php';
        include 'somefile.php';
        include 'somefile2.php';
        $this->done=true;
    }
    public function finished(){
        return $this->done || (time() - $this->starttime < 20)
    }
}
$worker=new workerThread();
$worker->start();
while(!$worker->finished()){}
```

Comment: No, not if you're trying to gracefully handle the timeout.

Comment: I have tried that but it gives fatal error that I can't catch and the loop can't stop

Comment: Well, you may try threads then. See [here](http://php.net/manual/de/class.thread.php).