# Break While Cycle with time duration on include. Multi files

Tags: php

I have 2 files running on loop, master.php and bot.php:

**master.php**

```
<?php
       while (1) {   
            include 'bot.php'; 
            sleep(60);
        }
```

**bot.php**

```
<?php
declare(ticks=1);

define('START_TIME', time());

// lambda uses START_TIME constant
register_tick_function(function() {
    if (time() - START_TIME > 9000) {
        echo 'Script execution halted. Took more than 20 seconds';
        exit(1);
    }
}, true);

     include_once 'onefile.php';
     include 'somefile.php';
     include 'somefile2.php';
?>
```

I need to ensure that bot.php doesn't take longer than x seconds.
If it does I need to gracefully stop/break the bot.php loop but keep the master.php running the infinite loop.

I have tried Josh Trii Johnston's answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356726/while-cycle-with-time-duration-on-include) but the problem is that it stops everything including master.php loop (which is the file I will initially run and I don't want to stop)

I need to create this timeout because bot.php performs some tasks on remote servers and sometimes (rarely) it time-outs and freezes forever. This timeout is just to ensure that in those cases the loop will break and a new cycle begin.

Comment: If you run bot.php via cron, you will not need gracefully stop/break the bot.php and you can use method that you already found then. So - as solution - just do not use master.php. Use cron for bot.php instead.

Comment: We are on a windows VPS.. am not sure if its even possible to make cronjobs here

Comment: It was! I used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701861/how-do-i-run-a-php-script-using-windows-schedule-task. Make a answer telling that and I will award you if you want. TY

Comment: You also can do it like

`$result = shell_exec('php bot.php');`